# Is there a way to hand-code a reference to a block?, in a .tpl file?

Tags: theming, commerce

Is there a way to hand-code a reference to a specific block?, in a .tpl file?

Specifically what i’m trying to do is this. I have a Drupal commerce site and the shopping cart contents are displayed via a block view. The contents are nicely hidden until the user mouses over a link. 
This is accomplished via the Ajax commerce cart module.

My global nav is hand-coded via a block-myNav.tpl.php file. 
So within the nav UL the pseudo code might look like

```
<li><?php print $my_block_reference here ?></li>
```

is that crazy? is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: While there are ways to do that, you should try to avoid it is possible. Your theme will break if someone will remove specified module, and that's a bad thing because your theme will not be able to prevent module or block removal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the down vote to what probably should be the correct answer to this post is b/c the answer did not have any code.

The way to render a block is:

```
<?php
  //D7
    $block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'block_delta');
    print render($block['content']);
?>
```

That can be placed in the template file that you want the block to show. See [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/26502) for information on what the vars are in that snippet of code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of modules that you should look at.  Context and Display Suite.

[Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context)....

> Context allows you to manage contextual conditions and reactions for
>   different portions of your site. You can think of each context as
>   representing a "section" of your site. For each context, you can
>   choose the conditions that trigger this context to be active and
>   choose different aspects of Drupal that should react to this active
>   context.

As for [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds)....

> Display Suite allows you to take full control over how your content is
>   displayed using a drag and drop interface. Arrange your nodes, views,
>   comments, user data etc. the way you want without having to work your
>   way through dozens of template files.

Between these two modules, you will probably never have to hack a template file again.

Answer (score 1):

You can see [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/26502). This way to placing the contents of a block in any location